# bxSlider - Animate/CSS on current slide only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, bxslider

I'm using bxslider in my wordpress theme, and everything seems to be working fine, but what i would like to do is apply some css to the current slide only.

i have multiple sliders on my page (each post in the wordpress loop pulls a slider and places it above the excerpt. what i want to achieve is that the current image in any slider has a full opacity of 1, where-as the non-current images have an opacity of 0.7

currently i've achieved this using some css and the following on the bxslider query:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            onSlideBefore: function (currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
    $('img.attachment-thumbnail-size').removeClass('active');
    $('img.attachment-thumbnail-size').eq(currentSlideHtmlObject+1).addClass('active')
    var current = $('img.attachment-thumbnail-size').attr('id');
    $('#team-member').load('load_member.php?id='+current); 
  }
    });
})
```

but this only works for the first slider in the loop, the second one doesn't seem to carry through with the adding of classes by the looks of things?

the build in progress can be seen at http://google-boost.co.uk

Thanks!

Comment: I have answered this question in detail on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351541/target-active-slide-and-add-css-class/18357158#18357158 Check it and if my solution helps dont forget to upvote.

Comment: Hey MarsOne, Cheers for that mate, but i'm still having some issues, the issue seems to be more with the other instances of the slider on the page, the first slider works fine, but as there are multiple sliders, it doesn't seem to carry over the information and just sets all the image opacity of the others to .7

Comment: Well it may be an issue regarding the class names. Have you tried referencing the sliders by ID instead of class. Give your 2 sliders uniques id's and then in your JS write 2 methods for the 2 id's...

Comment: The problem i have is, at it's in the loop there's potentially infinite slides, for every post there'll be a slide, a certain number of posts will only be loaded via an infiteloading but there'll still need to be an 'infinite' number of slides :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is just an idea how it must works (not tested)

But the idea, you need separate for onSliderLoad (this will be for the first slide) and onSlideBefore (this should works for each next slide). Please see my function parameters, I am using bxSlider v4.1.1, so you will need update with your current version

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    onSliderLoad: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){ 
      var cur = $('ul.bxslider').find('li:eq('+($slideElement+1)+')');
      var current = cur.find('img.attachment-thumbnail-size');
      current.addClass('active');
      $('#team-member').load('load_member.php?id='+current.attr('id')); 
    },
    onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){  
      $('img.attachment-thumbnail-size').removeClass('active');
      var cur = $('ul.bxslider').find('li:eq('+($slideElement+1)+')');
      var current = cur.find('img.attachment-thumbnail-size');
      current.addClass('active');
      $('#team-member').load('load_member.php?id='+current.attr('id')); 
    }
  });
})
```